# how to disable soft home key programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-homebutton

Is there any way to disable soft Home key Programatically?

```
public boolean isSoftKeyAvail(Context context) {
    final boolean[] isSoftkey = {false};
    final View activityRootView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int rootViewHeight = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight();
            int viewHeight = activityRootView.getHeight();
            int heightDiff = rootViewHeight - viewHeight;
            if (heightDiff > 100) { // 99% of the time the height diff will be due to a keyboard.
                isSoftkey[0] = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return isSoftkey[0];
}

public int getStatusBarHeight(){
    int result=0;
    int resourceId= mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if(resourceId >0)
        result = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Or set the manifest as:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
```

Comment: try this :
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```